# Setting up routing between disparate networks across a VPN

Tags: ubuntu, routing

I have an OpenVPN server at location A and a client at location B.  The firewall/router at location B has routes setup for the VPN network and the local network at location A.  The client has IP forward turned on and iptables forward rules for traffic in and out of the remote networks and the local network.  I can ping from the firewall to the VPN IP of the client, but I can't ping anything across the VPN.

**Network Addresses**

```
Router Location A 192.168.69.1/24
OpenVPN Server enp5s0 192.168.69.69/24
OpenVPN Server tun0 172.16.0.1/24

Router Location B 192.168.1.253/24
OpenVPN Client eno1 192.168.1.174/24
OpenVPN Client tun0 172.16.0.254/24
```

**Routes**

```
Router Location A:
    192.168.1.0/24 via 192.168.69.69
    172.16.0.0/24 via 192.168.69.69

OpenVPN Server:
    default via 192.168.69.1 dev enp5s0 proto dhcp metric 100 
    169.254.0.0/16 dev enp5s0 scope link metric 1000 
    172.16.0.0/24 dev tun0 proto kernel scope link src 172.16.0.1 
    192.168.1.0/24 via 172.16.0.254 dev tun0 
    192.168.69.0/24 dev enp5s0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.69.69 metric 100

Router Location B:
    192.168.69.0/24 via 192.168.1.174
    172.16.0.0/24 via 192.168.1.174

OpenVPN Client:
    default via 192.168.1.253 dev eno1 proto dhcp src 192.168.1.174 metric 100 
    172.16.0.0/24 via 172.16.0.1 dev tun0 
    192.168.1.0/24 dev eno1 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.1.174 metric 100 
    192.168.1.252 dev eno1 proto dhcp scope link src 192.168.1.174 metric 100 
    192.168.1.253 dev eno1 proto dhcp scope link src 192.168.1.174 metric 100 
    192.168.69.0/24 via 172.16.0.1 dev tun0
```

**IPTables**

```
OpenVPN Server:
    iptables -A FORWARD -s 192.168.69.0/24 -d 192.168.1.0/24 -i enp5s0 -o tun0 -j ACCEPT
    iptables -A FORWARD -s 192.168.1.0/24 -d 192.168.69.0/24 -i tun0 -o enp5s0 -j ACCEPT
    iptables -A FORWARD -s 172.16.0.0/24 -d 192.168.69.0/24 -i tun0 -o enp5s0 -j ACCEPT
    iptables -A FORWARD -s 192.168.69.0/24 -d 172.16.0.0/24 -i enp5s0 -o tun0 -j ACCEPT

Router Location B:
    iptables -A FORWARD -s 192.168.1.0/24 -d 172.16.0.0/24 -j ACCEPT
    iptables -A FORWARD -s 172.16.0.0/24 -d 192.168.1.0/24 -j ACCEPT
    iptables -A FORWARD -s 192.168.69.0/24 -d 192.168.1.0/24 -j ACCEPT
    iptables -A FORWARD -s 192.168.1.0/24 -d 192.168.69.0/24 -j ACCEPT

OpenVPN Client:
    iptables -A FORWARD -s 192.168.1.0/24 -d 172.16.0.0/24 -i eno1 -o tun0 -j ACCEPT
    iptables -A FORWARD -s 192.168.69.0/24 -d 192.168.1.0/24 -i tun0 -o eno1 -j ACCEPT
    iptables -A FORWARD -s 172.16.0.0/24 -d 192.168.1.0/24 -i tun0 -o eno1 -j ACCEPT
    iptables -A FORWARD -s 192.168.1.0/24 -d 192.168.69.0/24 -i eno1 -o tun0 -j ACCEPT
```

The router/firewall at location A is a TP Link firewall/router/AP.  The remaining devices are all Ubuntu machines.

The OpenVPN client can ping the OpenVPN server and the router at location A, but nothing else.  The router at location B can ping the OpenVPN interface of the OpenVPN client [172.16.0.254], but nothing else in that range.  It seems that only traffic that originates on the members of the VPN, actually cross the VPN to the other side, but anything physically located at location A can communicate with any part of the VPN or local network that is at that site and anything physically located at location B can communicate with anything else on that side of the VPN, but location A and location B can not communicate with each other via the VPN.

Comment: I would suggest that you group info per host, ordered in one of the directions of the traffic flow. It gives at least me a headache with this tree like grouping that branches from the type of info + location, if it's not confusing to most other people.

Comment: One route that is apparently missing (on the VPN client) is one for `192.168.69.0/24`

Comment: Also there's no rule for `-i enp5s0 -o tun0 -s 192.168.69.0/24 -d 172.16.0.0/24` on the VPN server

Comment: I updated and added some more information on routes and iptable rules.  I also re-organized the information to hopefully make it more reader friendly for @TomYan.